# Vertica SQL for running count distinct and running conditional count

Tags: sql, count, vertica

I'm trying to build a department level score table based on a deeper product url level score table.

1. Date is not consecutive
2. Not all urls got score updates at same day (independent to each other)
3. dist_url should be running count distinct (cumulative count distinct)
4. dist urls and urls score >=30 are both count distinct

What I have now is:

```
   Date  url   Store   Dept   Page   Score   
   10/1   a      US      A      X      10   
   10/1   b      US      A      X      30  
   10/1   c      US      A      X      60
   10/4   a      US      A      X      20  
   10/4   d      US      A      X      60
   10/6   b      US      A      X      22 
   10/9   a      US      A      X      40
   10/9   e      US      A      X      10


   Date  Store   Dept   Page   dist urls   urls score >=30  
   10/1   US      A      X          3          2 
   10/4   US      A      X          4          3
   10/6   US      A      X          4          2
   10/9   US      A      X          5          2
```

I think the dist_url can be done by using window function, just not sure on query.

Current query is as below, but it's wrong since not cumulative count distinct:

```
   SELECT
        bm.AnalysisDate,
        su.SoID         AS Store,
        su.DptCaID      AS DTID,
        su.PageTypeID   AS PTID,
        COUNT(DISTINCT bm.SeoURLID) AS NumURLsWithDupScore,
        SUM(CASE WHEN bm.DuplicationScore > 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Over30Count
    FROM csn_seo.tblBotifyMetrics bm 
    INNER JOIN csn_seo.tblSEOURLs su 
        ON bm.SeoURLID = su.ID
    WHERE su.DptCaID IS NOT NULL 
        AND su.DptCaID <> 0    
        AND su.PageTypeID IS NOT NULL
        AND su.PageTypeID <> -1
        AND bm.iscompliant = 1
    GROUP BY bm.AnalysisDate, su.SoID, su.DptCaID, su.PageTypeID;
```

Please let me know if anyone has any idea.

Comment: Is `urls score >=30` a running count, or a count for just one month? In both cases, I cannot explain the results that you are getting in this column. Is this a glitch in your sample data, else can you explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question, you seem to want two levels of logic:

```
select date, store, dept,
       sum(sum(start)) over (partition by dept, page order by date) as distinct_urls,
       sum(sum(start_30)) over (partition by dept, page order by date) as distinct_urls_30
from ((select store, dept, page, url, min(date) as date, 1 as start, 0 as start_30
       from t
       group by store, dept, page, url 
      ) union all
      (select store, dept, page, url, min(date) as date, 0, 1
       from t
       where score >= 30
       group by store, dept, page, url 
      )
     ) t
group by date, store, dept, page;
```

I don't understand how your query is related to your question.

Comment: It works! But do you know how to add a second bucket like "start_50" after start_30? I tried below but it doesn't work.

Comment: (select store, DTID, PTID, SeoURLID, min(analysisdate) as analysisdate, 1 as start, 0 as start_50
       from csn_junk.Botifypgpre
       group by store, DTID, PTID, SeoURLID
      ) union all
      (select store, DTID, PTID, SeoURLID, min(analysisdate) as analysisdate, 1 as START, 0 as start_75
       from csn_junk.Botifypgpre
       where score between 51 and 75
       group by store, DTID, PTID, SeoURLID
       ) union all

Comment: @Virgil . . . You can follow the same pattern, with another `union all` and another column.

Answer (score 0):

Try as I might, I don't get your output either:

But I think you can avoid UNION SELECTs - Does this do what you expect?
NULLS don't figure in COUNT DISTINCTs - and here you can combine an aggregate expression with an OLAP one ...
And Vertica has named windows to increase readability ....

```
WITH                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
input(Date,url,Store,Dept,Page,Score) AS (
          SELECT DATE '2019-10-01','a','US','A','X',10
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2019-10-01','b','US','A','X',30
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2019-10-01','c','US','A','X',60
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2019-10-04','a','US','A','X',20
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2019-10-04','d','US','A','X',60
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2019-10-06','b','US','A','X',22
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2019-10-09','a','US','A','X',40
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2019-10-09','e','US','A','X',10
)
SELECT
  date
, store
, dept
, page
, SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT url)                              ) OVER(w) AS dist_urls
, SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN score >=30 THEN url END)) OVER(w) AS dist_urls_gt_30
FROM input
GROUP BY
  date
, store
, dept
, page
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY store,dept,page ORDER BY date)
;
-- out     date    | store | dept | page | dist_urls | dist_urls_gt_30 
-- out ------------+-------+------+------+-----------+-----------------
-- out  2019-10-01 | US    | A    | X    |         3 |               2
-- out  2019-10-04 | US    | A    | X    |         5 |               3
-- out  2019-10-06 | US    | A    | X    |         6 |               3
-- out  2019-10-09 | US    | A    | X    |         8 |               4
-- out (4 rows)
-- out 
-- out Time: First fetch (4 rows): 45.321 ms. All rows formatted: 45.364 ms
```